# Add-Printer to two printservers at the same time

Tags: powershell

I know it's possible, but I dont know how. I'm new into PowerShell scripting and have made a little script that can add a printer to a print server..

How can I add the printer to both of our print servers in the same script?

```
Add-PrinterPort -Name PortName -ComputerName PRINTSRV1

Add-Printer -ComputerName PRINTSRV1 -Name PrinterName -ShareName ShareName -Shared -DriverName PrinterDriver -PortName PrinterPort -Comment PrinterModel -Location PrinterLocation -Published
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's how I'd do it:

```
$Computers = 'PRINTSRV1','PRINTSRV2'
foreach ($c in $Computers){
    Add-PrinterPort -Name PortName -ComputerName $c
    Add-Printer -ComputerName $c -Name PrinterName -ShareName ShareName -Shared -DriverName PrinterDriver -PortName PortName -Comment PrinterModel -Location PrinterLocation
}
```

Comment: Nice with quick respons. Thx both of you. I'll definetly try them both tommorow at work! I'll come back.

Answer (score 1):

Make a variable that's a list of the server names you want to target, then use `foreach` to iterate through them all:

```
$ServerList = @('PRINTSRV1','PRINTSRV2',PRINTSRV3');

foreach ($Server in $ServerList) {
    Add-PrinterPort -Name PortName -ComputerName $Server;

    Add-Printer -ComputerName $Server -Name PrinterName -ShareName ShareName `
        -Shared -DriverName PrinterDriver -PortName PrinterPort -Comment PrinterModel `
        -Location PrinterLocation -Published;
}
```

Comment: Nice with quick respons. Thx both of you. I'll definetly try them both tommorow at work! I'll come back.